# Ember.js adding and removing views from the DOM?

Tags: ember.js

I am looking into ember.js, after working with SproutCore 1 previously. I am looking for some examples on how to add and remove views from the DOM as the user navigates the application.

For instance, I have an application that contains a set of cases and each case has a workflow. There are also administration pages, etc.

When the user starts up the app, a dashboard-like user interface is shown. From here the user is able to search or click on a case in order to bring up that case. At this point I want to do the following:

- I want to remove the GUI for the Dashboard, and i want to show the GUI for the case - which is a complex GUI in itself with its own set of navigation rules etc.
- Also, within the case I want to add and remove portions of the GUI as the user navigates and manipulates the case.
- When the user clicks on the "Dashboard" link, I want the current GUI to be removed, and the dashboard to be added again.

As this will be a somewhat large application I am not sure if toggling the isVisible parameter is sufficient, or if other measures needs to be taken in order to not overload the user's browser.

Is there a guide, or an example that shows how to do this ?

Comment: You should look at the code for [ember-states](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/tree/master/packages/ember-states).

Comment: ud3323: Thanks, I have, but that leaves two questions: 1. How do I add and remove childViews, and 2. where in the code do I say MyApp.statemanager.create() ? Putting that code inside Ember.Application.create({ready: function({ //here })});, seems to load the statechart just before the views that are created in my index.html.

Comment: The one of the big differences between the old SC 1.x statecharts and the new ember-states is ViewStates. Basically it handles add/removal of views within your statechart. As for your other question, when you call Ember.StateManager.create that should initialize the statechart and enter your initial state for you.

Comment: I just noticed ViewStates, just before reading this comment, and I must say, they are vey nice indeed!. In case someone else is looking for how to use them, I found this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pangratz666/Y7dqt/

Comment: How to deal with childViews though? Here is a jsFiddle to explain the question: http://jsfiddle.net/GyZgy/3/

Comment: @Rajat I have updated your jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/joachimhs/GyZgy/4/ Is this what you are asking ?

Comment: @JoachimH.Skeie That is exactly what I was looking for. I was trying without a container view though.

Answer (score 9):

**WARNING: OUTDATED ANSWER**

A view inherits from `Ember.View` which means it gets some key methods. `append()`, which appends to `body`, `appendTo(arg)` which takes an argument and `remove()`.

The argument is a jQuery style selector of where to insert the element in the DOM.

```
// my view
App.PartsView = Ember.View.extend({
    ...
});


// create/insert my view
App.partsView = App.PartsView.create();
App.partsView.appendTo('#partcontainer');
```

In my code I have a `<div id="partcontainer"></div>`.

```
// remove from DOM
App.partsView.remove();
```

The documentation has a good part on [Building a View Hierarchy](http://emberjs.com/#toc_31) and later a section on `Ember.ContainerView` depending on whether you want to do it all programatically or not.

Comment: The jQuery documentation provides an [overview of available jQuery selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).

Comment: Question:  Should one do this? It seems to be a bit out of the normal way of doing things with Ember.

Comment: Good question. I wrote this almost two years ago, when emberjs was much more "unfinished", and I haven't stayed up-to-date with what's happening now. My answer may be outdated.

Comment: yes sadly it is outdated.  I have posted the issue for a specific version of ember 1.8 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27597066/creating-and-adding-new-ember-view-elements-to-the-dom-in-ember-version-1-8

Comment: i added a not about it being outdated