# creating and adding new Ember View elements to the DOM in ember version 1.8

Tags: ember.js

I have seen this work in previous versions of Ember but I cannot get it to work in version 1.8

I would like the **addNewView** method in the index controller to create and add new **App.ReusableView** with its designated template as an element to the DOM div.  I have tried several combinations and none work with this ember version.

OR, am I approaching this wrong and have the template using an {{#each}} to read from a model and have the controller just add elements to the controller?

**jsbin:** http://jsbin.com/xidoqo/1/edit?html,js,console,output

**error**

```
Error: Assertion Failed: You cannot append to an existing Ember.View. Consider using Ember.ContainerView instead.
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Playground Ember</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap-v3.1.1.min.css">
</head>
<body>

  <script type="text/x-handlebars">
    <h2>main page</h2>
    {{outlet}}
  </script>

  <script type="text/x-handlebars" id="index">
    <button {{action 'addNewView'}}>addNewView</button>
    <div id='divHolderId'></div>
  </script>

  <script type='text/x-handlebars' data-template-name='reusable'>
    my reusable view content
  </script>

  <script src="js/libs/jqueryv1.11.0.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/libs/bootstrapv3.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/libs/handlebars-v1.3.0.js"></script>
  <script src="js/libs/ember-1.8.1.js"></script>
  <script src="js/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**app.js**

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.IndexController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  actions: {
    addNewView: function() {
      console.log('addNewView called');
      var view = App.ReusableView.create();
      view.appendTo('#divHolderId'); // error: 
    }
  }
});

App.ReusableView = Ember.View.extend({
  templateName: 'reusable'
});
```

**edit1:** (also tried instantiating a ContainerView with the same error)

```
addNewView: function() {
  console.log('addNewView called');
  var container = Ember.ContainerView.create({
    childViews: [App.ReusableView.create()]
  });
  container.appendTo('#divHolderId');
}
```

Comment: Do as the error says, use an `Ember.ContainerView`. http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.ContainerView.html

Comment: @givanse, I have tried instantiating a ContainerView with my view as a childView but it still doesnt work. please see edit1 snippet in the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you absolutely must use views, then this will work: http://jsbin.com/zufomiweqe/2/edit

It's a little strange, though, the `Ember.ContainerView`'s API didn't really get too much love when it was implemented.  One of the bad things is that any actions to be triggered on the `ContainerView` have to be triggered via `view.parentView`, since the child views don't directly have access to the `ContainerView`'s context.

Try that out, though, I hope it works out for you :-)

Comment: thanks for the help but the jsbin you linked to shows an error in the console : "Script error. (line 0)"

Comment: Not sure why it did that... the last template was duplicated.  It's fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked out components at all?  What you're describing feels very much like the way that we did things in Ember before components existed, and it was all very unwieldy and error-prone.

I'm not sure about your specific use-case, but I would have an array that represents the contexts for your views, and clicking `addNewView` would simply push a context to the array.  In your template:

```
{{#each thing in contexts}}
  {{my-new-component thing}}
{{/each}}
```

Comment: Hi, yes you're right. I can do this with components but due to a restriction for this implementation I am restricted to use a View.  If I cannot find a solution I would have to convert all of these to Components.  Hopefully it wont come to that since itll be a lot of code to change.

Comment: A component technically is a subclass of `Ember.View`, it just happens to have a controller mixed in as well.  I understand about time lost in refactoring, but I'm wondering if components won't save you time in the long run.  Many modern Ember apps don't even implement their own views, because they don't really accomplish anything that components can't do better.